# Use mysql to create a modified string searching for words within that string contained in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I hope I can explain well enough what I am looking for.  I tried doing some searches on here, but wasn't finding what I want.  I want to do this with strictly mysql if I can with no PHP involved.

So I have a table with terms in it with URL links for each term, we'll call that `terms`.  I have another table with short paragraphs of text we'll call `paragraphs`.  What I want to do is select a `paragraph` from the table and search it for any of the words contained in the `terms` table.  If the term is in the text, I want to replace it with a concatenated html anchor tag using data from the `terms` table. I then want the paragraph returned as a formatted string with the anchor tags in place. This way if I add or remove terms to or from the table, I always get a paragraph formatted with the most up to date terms.

Let me know if this is too confusing and I'll see if I can explain it better.  Also, if I missed something in my searching that is already posted for this, feel free to guide me in that direction.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
-------------------------------------------------
Edit: Here is an example.
-------------------------------------------------
`terms` table
-------------------------------------------------
ID |   term   |   URL 
---|----------|----------------------------------
1  | printer  | http://t-shooting.link/printers
2  | scanner  | http://t-shooting.link/scanners
3  | copier   | http://t-shooting.link/copier
-------------------------------------------------

`problems` table
ID |      problem
---|---------------------------------------------
1  | the two printers (side by side) need cleaning as the 
   | copies from them come out with streaks.
2  | My computer won't recognize scanner when I try to use 
   | it. I was able to use the copier to scan for now, but
   | it would be nice to use the scanner that I have in my 
   | room.
```

So if I select ID 2 from the `problems` table I need it to search for any words contained in the `terms` table and replace them with a mysql "CONCAT('`<a href="`', `terms`.`URL`, '`">`', `terms`.`term`, '`</a>`')" or however I decide to format that. This would make the paragraph look like this:

**My computer won't recognize `<a href="http://t-shooting.link/scanner">scanner</a>` when I try to use it. I was able to use the `<a href="http://t-shooting.link/copier">copier</a>` to scan for now, but it would be nice to use the `<a href="http://t-shooting.link/scanner">scanner</a>` that I have in my room.**

The more I do on the mysql side, the less overhead I have on the PHP side.  I know ways to do this in PHP, I am just wondering if there is a way to do it in mysql.

Does that help a bit?

Comment: letting me know what?  That it is confusing?

Comment: with no PHP involved. is it possible?

Comment: Dan, I think you need to show some examples, or this gets closed

Comment: I will edit with an example

Comment: I suspect that this will be easier to apply as script in your html - not that I necessarily know how to do that